# c:out tag not printing value

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I was following [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/jstl-core-forEach-tag) jstl tutorial.
I am trying to print values in a `c:forEach` loop, but the value for `i` is not being printed.

My code:

```
<%--
    Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
    User: Jaideep Shekhar
    Date: 25.11.2020
    Time: 15:00
    To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="10">
        <h1><c:out value="${i}"/></h1>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is:

```
${i}
${i}
${i}
${i}
${i}
${i}
${i}
${i}
${i}
${i}
${i}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just replace this 
<%@ taglib  uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

Comment: @anuresh does it work for you? Because this references a file, and not a url.

Comment: JSTL is working perfectly fine. If it didn't work fine, then you wouldn't have seen anything printed at all, for sure not 10 times exactly as instructed to your `<c:forEach>`. It would have remained hidden in the generated HTML output. It's just EL which is in turn not working.

Comment: @BalusC the theory is all well and fine, but is there a solution? I know JSTL is working, but `c:out` is not, which is why I gave you the output.

Comment: See link to duplicate question in top of your question. The answer is over there.

Comment: @BalusC Aah, I see that there is an incorrect `<!DOCTYPE>` there. Removed, and it works. Do I delete the question?